# Safari not executing jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I have a form with 2 drop down boxes. The selection of the first box affects the output of the second box. The jQuery works in chrome and firefox but I do not have a clue why it doesn't work in safari.

I have worked out that the function is being triggered initially when the page is loaded however it is not affecting the select tags or being triggered afterwards.

I know something must be wrong otherwise it would be working. But it seems to be safari specific. As I only new to using jQuery I apologise for the vague question but i've spent the last few days trying to figure this out.

My question is what wrong?

The version of safari is 9.

This is the function that is being triggered initially but not afterwards or affecting the form.

```
$(function(){

$("#groups").on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var sub = $("#sub_groups");
    $("option", sub).filter(function(){
        if (
             $(this).attr("data-group") === val
          || $(this).attr("data-group") === "SHOW"
        ) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
$("#groups").trigger('change');
```

});

Here is the table it should be affecting

```
<table id="quote_form_table"border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;width:100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                <tr>
                        <th class="quantitiyH">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="other">Item</th>
                        <th class="other">Unit Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="hidden"><input type="text" name="H1" value="active"></td>
                        <td><input class="input " type="number" name="Q1" min="1" max="200"></td>
                        <td><select name="P1" id="groups">
                      <option value="none">None</option>
                      <option value="Health & Safety Signs">Health & Safety Signs</option>
                      <option value="Portable Displays & Counters">Portable Displays & Counters</option>
                      <option value="Roller Banner">Roller Banner</option>
                      <option value="Canvas Printing">Canvas Printing</option>
                      <option value="Exterior Signs">Exterior Signs</option>
                      <option value="Exibition Design & Instalation">Exibition Design & Insalation</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                        <td>
                      <select name="T1" id="sub_groups" >
                        <option data-group='SHOW' value='0'>-- Select --</option>
                        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Di Bond'>Di Bond</option>
                        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='PVC'>PVC</option>
                        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Self Adhesive'>Self Adhesive</option>
                        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Floor Vinyls'>Floor Vinyls</option>

                          <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Pop up Display'>Pop up Display</option>
                          <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Table & Case to counter'>Table & Case to counter</option>
                          <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Replacement Graphics'>Replacement Graphics</option>

                            <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Grass Hopper'>Grass Hopper</option>
                            <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Excalibur'>Excalibur</option>
                            <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Replacement Graphics'>Replacement Graphics</option>

                              <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Standard'>Standard</option>
                              <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Waterproof Latex'>Waterproof latex</option>
                              <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Photo Realistic'>Photo Realistic</option>

                                <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Full Color'>Full Color</option>
                                <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Vinyl Cut'>Vinyl Cut</option>
                                <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Gloss Laminate'>Gloss Laminate</option>

                                  <option data-group="Exibition Design & Instalation" value='Standard'>Standard</option>
                                  </select>
                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                  <button type="button"onclick="addrow()">Add Row</button>
                  <button type="button"onclick="removerow()">Remove Row</button>
```

I do know that inline css and using IDs are not the best and I will be tidying them up afterwards.

EDIT -- Only error messages showing are for css * selector

EDIT -- console.log

```
$(function(){
  console.log(1);
  $("#groups").on('change', function(){
    console.log(2);
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(3);
    var sub = $("#sub_groups");
    console.log(4);
 $("option", sub).filter(function(){
    if (
         $(this).attr("data-group") === val
      || $(this).attr("data-group") === "SHOW"
    ) {  
      console.log(5);
        $(this).show();
    } else {  console.log(6);
        $(this).hide();
    }
      console.log(7);
    });
    });
      console.log(8);
       $("#groups").trigger('change');
      console.log(9);

});
```

Comment: what error you are getting in browser console?

Comment: In which OS are you checking?

Comment: The only errors I find using the error console in safari are ones for css. Which is the  * selector. No other errors appear.

Comment: I am currently using OS X El Capitan version 10.11.

Comment: Yes some of jquery problem  with  EL Captain  MAC

Comment: Do console(1) , console(2) , console(3) on each step and check browser console where you get failed.

Comment: I new that that's y i asking for OS you are using. I face some of problem and trace.

Comment: have you trace it? on which line you get failed?

Comment: try with `$(document).ready(function(){});` put inside it.

Comment: Sorry Parth could you please explain further? or provide an example as I do not understand what exactly to do. Do you mean $(document).ready(function(){console(1});?

Comment: Put console.log(1), console.log(2)....on function where you think problem is and check where it get failed logging. On that line problem is. we have to find that problematic line.

Comment: All console.log were triggered. In this order
1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7 ..... 9

Comment: On which line it gets failed.may be problem with `trigger`. write `$("#groups").change();` only.

Comment: Using  $("#groups").change(); instead of $("#groups").trigger('change'); still causes triggers but still not working.

Comment: what problem you are facing from `safari` then other browser?

Answer (score 1):

I have made smoe changes in your function and thats works fine.

```js
$(function() {  
  var removedElement="";
  $("#groups").change(function() {
    $("#sub_groups").append(removedElement);
    var val = $(this).val();    
    removedElement = $("#sub_groups option").filter(function(i) {              
        return (!($(this).data("group") == val || $(this).data("group") == "SHOW"));      
    }).remove();    
  });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<table id="quote_form_table" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;width:100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <th class="quantitiyH">Quantity</th>
    <th class="other">Item</th>
    <th class="other">Unit Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidden">
      <input type="text" name="H1" value="active">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="input " type="number" name="Q1" min="1" max="200">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="P1" id="groups">
        <option value="none">None</option>
        <option value="Health & Safety Signs">Health & Safety Signs</option>
        <option value="Portable Displays & Counters">Portable Displays & Counters</option>
        <option value="Roller Banner">Roller Banner</option>
        <option value="Canvas Printing">Canvas Printing</option>
        <option value="Exterior Signs">Exterior Signs</option>
        <option value="Exibition Design & Instalation">Exibition Design & Insalation</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="T1" id="sub_groups">
        <option data-group='SHOW' value='0'>-- Select --</option>
        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Di Bond'>Di Bond</option>
        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='PVC'>PVC</option>
        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Self Adhesive'>Self Adhesive</option>
        <option data-group='Health & Safety Signs' value='Floor Vinyls'>Floor Vinyls</option>

        <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Pop up Display'>Pop up Display</option>
        <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Table & Case to counter'>Table & Case to counter</option>
        <option data-group='Portable Displays & Counters' value='Replacement Graphics'>Replacement Graphics</option>

        <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Grass Hopper'>Grass Hopper</option>
        <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Excalibur'>Excalibur</option>
        <option data-group='Roller Banner' value='Replacement Graphics'>Replacement Graphics</option>

        <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Standard'>Standard</option>
        <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Waterproof Latex'>Waterproof latex</option>
        <option data-group='Canvas Printing' value='Photo Realistic'>Photo Realistic</option>

        <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Full Color'>Full Color</option>
        <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Vinyl Cut'>Vinyl Cut</option>
        <option data-group='Exterior Signs' value='Gloss Laminate'>Gloss Laminate</option>

        <option data-group="Exibition Design & Instalation" value='Standard'>Standard</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="addrow()">Add Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removerow()">Remove Row</button>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in safari. I tried to run your code in safari and ran into he same problems as I face.

Comment: @SamCraddock i have change in my code and it works in safari also please check. and i workd hard to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes working in safari also. Thanks @AnkitKathiriya. May be problem with `select` `option` `show/hide`.

Comment: Yes @ParthTrivedi we can't `hide` `show` option in all browser there for  i use `remove` and `append`  and it works in all browser.